# powershell to get the first x MB of a file

Tags: powershell

Its pretty straightforward to get the first x lines of a text file, but I need the first x MB of a file.  Given that I'm a PowerShell neophyte if you could please give me some annotations on the script that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18936628/2707864) worked for me. And it does not traverse the whole file as `get-content`, so it is most convenient for large files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Get-Content foo.exe -TotalCount 1MB -Encoding byte
```

If you happen to be using [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) then do this:

```
Format-Hex foo.exe -count 1MB
```

Note: If you are using PowerShell V2 be sure to grab the 1.2 beta of PSCX.

Answer (score 2):

Independent of PowerShell, I'd just use the `head` command. (It's a standard Unix command, but [it's available for Windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).) The `-c` option lets you specify the number of bytes you want.

```
head -c 1024 foo.exe
```

Comment: One of the reasons I loath asking powershell questions is the for the obvious "you could do it unix with ...." answers.  there's got to be a dozen of non-powershell ways of getting what I'm looking for, but I"m looking for a powershell answer.

Comment: And I don't understand why anyone would restrict solutions to PowerShell when there are solutions that work everywhere, not just PowerShell. I mean, unless it's just idle curiosity: "Gee, I wonder if I can do that in PowerShell." You didn't say it needed to be a PowerShell-only solution. I figured you're just sitting at a PS prompt and wondering how to get the first N bytes of a file. The answer is the same as if you were sitting at any other prompt, and it's not a Unix solution, either.

Comment: Maybe someday you don't want to read the first 1 KiB of a file but from a binary registry key. Also, there are ofttimes things you miss in a new technology because you're too accustomed doing it your old-fashioned way. You wouldn't recommend using sed/awk on wmic output to a Powershell user, would you? Also, head (being not a cmdlet) will yield a string[] which may not be what you want.

Comment: It's important to realize that there are often cases where a machine is locked down so that you can't install new software, but you *can* run PowerShell.  That's a good use-case for "want  PowerShell, can't use X ported unix executable"