# In Powershell, How do I split a large binary file?

Tags: powershell

I've seen the answer elsewhere for text files, but I need to do this for a compressed file.

I've got a 6G binary file which needs to be split into 100M chunks.  Am I missing the analog for  unix's "head" somewhere?

Comment: this looks interesting: http://blogs.sans.org/windows-security/2010/02/11/powershell-byte-array-hex-convert/

Comment: this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888063/powershell-to-get-the-first-x-mb-of-a-file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Never mind. Here  you go:

```
function split($inFile,  $outPrefix, [Int32] $bufSize){

  $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($inFile)
  $chunkNum = 1
  $barr = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

  while( $bytesRead = $stream.Read($barr,0,$bufsize)){
    $outFile = "$outPrefix$chunkNum"
    $ostream = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($outFile)
    $ostream.Write($barr,0,$bytesRead);
    $ostream.close();
    echo "wrote $outFile"
    $chunkNum += 1
  }
}
```

Assumption: bufSize fits in memory.

Comment: why do we need `$stream.seek`? The Read method automatically sets the current position, right?

Comment: You're probably right, @Samik.  If you can test it to ensure that it works, I'll remove the line of code.

Comment: Yes, I commented out the three lines involving $curOffset and it worked just as well. As I am using this script to split a text file, I had to add a few lines of code, so that it does not break in the middle of a line. Anyway, thanks for the code.

Answer (score 20):

The answer to the corollary question: How do you put them back together?

```
function stitch($infilePrefix, $outFile) {

    $ostream = [System.Io.File]::OpenWrite($outFile)
    $chunkNum = 1
    $infileName = "$infilePrefix$chunkNum"

    $offset = 0

    while(Test-Path $infileName) {
        $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($infileName)
        $ostream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Count)
        Write-Host "read $infileName"
        $chunkNum += 1
        $infileName = "$infilePrefix$chunkNum"
    }

    $ostream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered the question alluded to in this question's comments by bernd_k but I would use -`ReadCount` in this case instead of `-TotalCount` e.g.

```
Get-Content bigfile.bin -ReadCount 100MB -Encoding byte
```

This causes `Get-Content` to read a chunk of the file at a time where the chunk size is either a line for text encodings or a byte for byte encoding.  Keep in mind that when it does this, you get an array passed down the pipeline and not individual bytes or lines of text.

Comment: ...right, and then you need to figure out a way to get each chunk into a different file.  

The Jason Fossen link above  recommends against manipulating large sets of data with get-content:


"performance of get-content is horrible with large files.  Unless you are reading less than 200KB, don’t use get-content..."

Is that your experience?

Comment: Also, can you express this as a complete solution akin to mine above?

Comment: Got a chance to try this on a huge file and yeah, unless you've got a 64-bit PowerShell, forget about it.  :-)  I've had pretty good luck with read counts of 1KB but getting Get-Content to parcel it up into chunks of 100MB just doesn't scale. Too bad PowerShell can't handle this a bit more directly.