# Create a small file(.txt or .TMP) from a huge .TMP file

Tags: powershell, out-of-memory, getcontent

'System.OutOfMemoryException' error occured while creating a small file from big file.

I usually use the below PowerShell command to create a small version of a huge file,

```
Get-Content input_file_name.Tmp -TotalCount 100 | Out-File -Encoding Default "output_file_name_100.Tmp"
```

However, this is throwing a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error. Any advise on this?

Note : It has worked earlier for bigger files. I think the size of the file is not the problem.

Comment: What are you really [trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? Maybe [.Net IO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4533835/503046) would work better?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I know that you personally think the size of the file may not be the actual problem, but it's worth revisiting the fundamentals for the benefit of other readers.</sup>

**[`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), when used in a pipeline, reads lines from a file *one at a time***.

This object-by-object processing is a core feature of PowerShell's pipeline and acts as a memory throttle (no need to read *all* input into memory *at once*.

There are **only three scenarios where `Get-Content` reads the *whole* file into memory**:

- If you capture `Get-Content`'s output in a *variable* (`$content = Get-Content ...`), in which case the variable receives an *array* comprising *all lines*.
- If you enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)`, `$(...)`, or `@(...)`, which also returns an array of all lines.
- If you use the `-Raw` switch, which makes `Get-Content` return a *single, multi-line* string.

---

Using `-TotalCount 100` (or `-First 100`) doesn't change this fundamental behavior: after `100` lines have been read, `Get-Content` stops reading and closes the file.

**The code in your question therefore doesn't explain your symptom** - you shouldn't run out of memory - at least not because the input file is large; if it still happens, you may be seeing a bug.

If you have a *reproducible* case, I encourage you to file a bug in the [Windows PowerShell  UserVoice forum](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) or, if you can (also) reproduce the bug in PowerShell [Core] v6+, at the [PowerShell Core GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

---

In the meantime, you can **consider using .NET directly, which also generally
*faster* than using PowerShell's cmdlets**:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Take([IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD/input_file_name.Tmp"), 100) |
  Out-File -Encoding Default output_file_name_100.Tmp
```

<sup>Note:

• The use of `"$PWD/"` as part of the input file path, because .NET's working directory typically differs from PowerShell's.

• In PowerShell type literals (`[...]`), the `System.` part of the full type name can be omitted; thus `[Linq.Enumerable]` refers to [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable), and `[IO.File]` to [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File)</sup>