# Get the first n characters of a large file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've got a huge XML file (0.5 GB), with no line breaks. I want to be able to look at, say, the first 200 characters without opening the whole file. Is there a way to do this with PowerShell?

Comment: looks to me that get-content is going to be effectively loading the whole file, so that's not what I'm looking for - unless there's some lazy evaluating magic in gc that I can't find any documentation for.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010158/2707864) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell can be used as a basis. It might work faster than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18936628/2707864) below if the fragment to extract is large. This is a conclusion that I obtained from non-systematic tests. Try it as you see fit.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### PowerShell Desktop (up to 5.1)

You can read at the byte level with Get-Content like so:

```
$bytes = Get-Content .\files.txt -Encoding byte -TotalCount 200
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
```

If the log file is ASCII you can simplify this to:

```
[char[]](Get-Content .\files.txt -Encoding byte -TotalCount 200)
```

### PowerShell Core 6.0 and newer

PowerShell Core doesn't support `byte` encoding. It's been replaced by `-AsByteStream` parameter.

```
$bytes = Get-Content .\file.txt -AsByteStream -TotalCount 200
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
```

Comment: The file is ASCII, and what worked best was the ascii version of your first answer. The second answer actually displayed as one line per character - a bit hard to read!

Comment: if you put a () around the whole thing and `-join ''` it will become one string again.

Comment: @Eris yes that will get it back to string form but the "() around the whole thing" bit is not necessary.

Comment: This worked great for me. And it does not traverse the whole file as `get-content`, so it is most convenient for large files.

Answer (score 1):

Copying binary files via [powershell commandlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783554/fast-and-simple-binary-concatenate-files-in-powershell) tend to be a bit slow. You may, however, run the following commands from powershell to get a decent performance:

```
cmd /c copy /b "large file.ext" "first n.ext"
FSUTIL file seteof "first n.ext" $nbytes
```

Tested in Win 10 PS 5.1
Result: 1.43GB processed in 4 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content takes a -ReadCount option so you can take only the first X lines.

If you really want character granularity, you'll need to use one of the [IO.File]::Read methods from .NET

Comment: sadly, there are no line breaks in the file so this is not an option

Answer (score 0):

[@keith-hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill) got me most of the way there.

Here's what I used to get the first character out of a VMware Virtual Disk. There is important information in the first 1000 or so characters, but I'd never get at it trying to open a 30GB file.

```
$bytes = Get-Content .\VMwareVirtualDiskFile.vmdk -Encoding byte -TotalCount 1000
[String]::Concat([char[]]($bytes))
```

Answer (score -2):

`(get-content myfile).Substring(0,x)`

Where x is the number of characters you want from each line e.g.
`$lines = (get-content myfile).Substring(0,10)` will return an array of strings where each member of the array contains the first 10 characters of each line in myfile.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider formatting you code differently than your text. 

You can use ` ` to wrap your code

Comment: this does not answer the original question, they wanted the first X bytes of the entire file, not per line. this method is also extremely inefficient for large files which was part of the original question.