# What is different between Get-content and [IO.File]::ReadAllText?

Tags: powershell, file-io, locking

If I read file that another process is occupied using Get-content, then working well.
But, read the file by [IO.File]::ReadAllText and display error message:
The file is occupied by another process.

Comment: Are you saying that the two methods do not act the same when trying to read from a file currently locked by another process? That would be unexpected - please update your question with a [mcve]. By contrast, the methods differ in what other processes are allowed to do with a file while these methods have a given file open - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619034/45375.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic concept between the two.

```
# returns array of lines in the file
Get-Content "FileName.txt"

# returns one string for whole file.
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("FileName.txt")

# There are ways to achieve second behavior with Get-Content, as of PowerShellv3 and later

Get-Content "FileName.txt" -Raw

# in PowerShell 2:
Get-Content "FileName.txt" | Out-String
```

Details are in the MS docs.

[File.​Read​All​Text  Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[Get-Content (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)

You can view the source code of Get-Content on the MS PowerShell GitHub page. 
If you really want to see what is under the covers, or you can use [Trace-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command) to see the steps taken when you use them in code.

Comment: Good general information, but - despite the question's generic title - it is not what the  OP is asking for. To complete the general information, I suggest pointing out the pitfall with using relative paths with .NET methods (different working directories). Also, as an alternative to piping to `Out-String` in v2 , `(Get-Content "FileName.txt") -join [Environment]::NewLine` avoids a trailing newline in the resulting string.