# Extract text from string to end of document

Tags: powershell

I have a file that is too large for me to open. However, I only need the last portion of this file. There is a line of text that includes this string: `DATA FROM NSERCH=   249`

If I can pull everything from that line to the end of the document, I should be able to open the file.

Comment: Are you saying this works if the file is smaller, and you only need to solve the file size issue?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know why I included that information in there. I literally just can't open the whole file in a text editor (it's over 1GB). But I know that the data that I need is in the last 10% of the file. So if I can produce a file that only contains that last 10% of text, I can get what I need.

Might be worth noting that I'm a chemist and not very proficient with PowerShell, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507343/get-last-n-lines-or-bytes-of-a-huge-file-in-windows-like-unixs-tail-avoid-ti

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-Content` cmdlet for this and read lines until it finds the string you choose as starting point for this:

```
$filename   = 'FULL PATH TO THE TOO LARGE TO OPEN FILE'
$outputPath = 'FULL PATH TO THE OUTPUT.TXT FILE'

$saveit = $false
Get-Content -Path $filename | ForEach-Object {
    # the $_ automatic variable represents a single line of the file
    if ($saveit) { 
        Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value $_ 
    }
    else {
        $saveit = ($_ -match 'DATA\s+FROM\s+NSERCH=\s+249')
    }
}
```

The code below does the exact same thing, but requires .NET 4.0 or higher, so if you are using PowerShell 3.0 or up, you can use the `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` method to speed things up:

```
$filename   = 'FULL PATH TO THE TOO LARGE TO OPEN FILE'
$outputPath = 'FULL PATH TO THE OUTPUT.TXT FILE'

$saveit = $false
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename)) {
    if ($saveit) { 
        Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value $line 
    }
    else {
        $saveit = ($line -match 'DATA\s+FROM\s+NSERCH=\s+249')
    }
}
```

Another `Get-Content` alternative could be:

```
$filename   = 'FULL PATH TO THE TOO LARGE TO OPEN FILE'
$outputPath = 'FULL PATH TO THE OUTPUT.TXT FILE'

$saveit = $false
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($filename)
while (!($reader.EndOfStream)) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    if ($saveit) { 
        Add-Content -Path $outputPath -Value $line 
    }
    else {
        $saveit = ($line -match 'DATA\s+FROM\s+NSERCH=\s+249')
    }
}
$reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: this is not a direct answer but a workaround to only search part of the file: check the last number of lines only. This can be done repeatedly by increasing the number of lines if needed.

The `Get-Content -Tail <number of lines>` parameter described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) specifies the number of lines from the end of a file or other item. You can use it to reduce the input. This parameter was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.