# How to read and edit (>3GB) csv file using Windows Batch?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am using the below FOR-IN-DO syntax to read and get the last row of (>3GB) csv files

```
For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In (test.csv) Do Set "lastline=%%A"
```

The code works for small files. However, the FOR-IN-DO cannot open the large csv files. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: it's bad idea to do such a thing in batch. It'll be extremely inefficient even if it's possible. Why not use a better scripting tool like powershell or python?

Comment: it's also bad to use csv for huge data structures. There are many better binary formats for this purpose

Comment: The `FOR` command reads the entire file into memory.  And because cmd.exe is a 32bit program it is limited to a file size of 2,147,483,647 bytes.  If you want to get the last line of a file I would recommend you use a tool designed for that purpose. Their are many ports of the command `TAIL` that work on Windows.  I would assume you could even call out to [Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507532/1417694) to accomplish this.

Comment: @Squashman on 64-bit Windows there are both 64-bit and 32-bit cmd.exe in `%windir%\System32` and `%windir%\SysWOW64` respectively

Comment: Thank you @phuclv . I will also try using batch to run powershell or vb script to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the content of your source file, i.e. the CSV is not <kbd>TAB</kbd> delimited, or contain <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters you need to preserve, you may be able to do it like this:

```sh
Set "SourceFile=test.csv"
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /V "" 0^<"%SourceFile%"') Do Set /A "TotalLines=%%G-1"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +%TotalLines% 0^<"%SourceFile%"') Do Set "LastLine=%%G"
```

---

Based upon your comment, I'd offer the following modification of the above:

```sh
Set "SourceFile=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.csv"
Set "DestinationDir=%UserProfile%\Documents"
Set "LineMatch=Specific String"
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C /V "" 0^<"%SourceFile%"') Do Set /A "TotalLines=%%G-1"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +%TotalLines% 0^<"%SourceFile%"') Do If /I "%%G" == "%LineMatch%" Move /Y "%SourceFile%" "%DestinationDir%"
```

Comment: Please note that this example is to reproduce filling the content of a variable with the last line of the file, which replicated your own code `For /F "UseBackQ Delims==" %%A In (test.csv) Do Set "lastline=%%A"`. Anything regarding modification of the content of the last line of that file is a different question, and therefore not covered in my above response.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is good enough, what I want is to read the last line of the CSV, and if if "%lastline%" == "%specific_string%", I will move the CSV file to another directory.

Comment: I've added an additional example to my above answer based upon your comment @plm0998, I hope it helps.